# What does this warning mean? WARNING:tensorflow:AutoGraph could not transform

Tags: python, tensorflow, huggingface-transformers

I'm finetuning a DistilBERT HuggingFace models and started getting this error today just before the training epochs start:

```
WARNING:tensorflow:AutoGraph could not transform <function infer_framework at 0x7d7820b4c5e0> and will run it as-is.
Cause: for/else statement not yet supported
To silence this warning, decorate the function with @tf.autograph.experimental.do_not_convert
```

I'm running the exact same code that I've been using for over a month now, but this is the first time that this warning has appeared. The models still seem to train regardless however. Does anyone know what it means? Since I'm only finetuning the pre-trained models, so I'm not sure that I can decorate the function in the way it suggests?